# Link directories in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

Hi I am on a CentOS server, I have a user called `'theowner'` so he has his folder under `/home/theowner`

In other hand I have 2 folders, f1 and f2 under `/home/myprojects/src` and I just want that these folders appears under `/home/theowner` but I don't want to move the folder
I want is to link that 2 folders to `/home/theowner`. It's for c9 workspace, and I just want to allow theowner to access that folders directly when he logins. Thanks!

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Lubomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8006535/lubomir) already gave a symlink solution.

However, his solution will require that `theowner` has at least a `read-execute` permission to all the parent directories of `/home/myprojects/src/f1` and `/home/myprojects/src/f2`.

In most situation, you don't want `theowner` to see anything outside of `/home/myprojects/src/f1` and `/home/myprojects/src/f2`.

Bind mount to the rescue.

As `theowner` create the following directories.

```
$ mkdir f1 f2
```

As `root`, mount the source directories to the target directories.

```
# mount -o bind /home/myprojects/src/f1 /home/theowner/f1
# mount -o bind /home/myprojects/src/f2 /home/theowner/f2
```

If you want it to persist across reboots, add the 2 entries in /etc/fstab

```
/home/myprojects/src/f1  /home/theowner/f1  auto  auto,bind  0 0
/home/myprojects/src/f2  /home/theowner/f2  auto  auto,bind  0 0
```

With this solution, `theowner` doesn't need to have access to the parent directories of `/home/myprojects/src/f1` and `/home/myprojects/src/f2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating symbolic links:

```
ln -s /home/myprojects/src/f1/ /home/theowner/

ln -s /home/myprojects/src/f2/ /home/theowner/
```

Comment: This will not work if `/home/myprojects/src` and parent directories are not accessible by `theowner`. You might want to a note that this condition should be met for this solution to work.

Comment: Indeed, it needs to be accessible by `theowner`, but he didn't mention this limitation in his question.